# SQL to split text, with a maximum of five words in each row in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table with a text field. I would like split the text every five words.

```
CREATE TABLE texts (text String) ENGINE=Memory;

INSERT INTO texts VALUES ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit');

SELECT text FROM texts;
```

Result:

| text |
| --- |
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit |

Result desired:

| text |
| --- |
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, |
| consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do |
| eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore |
| et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem |
| ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur |
| adipiscing elit |

Comment: For a set-based approach you need to 1. split the string on a space into rows, 2. apply a grouping to each set of 5 rows using window analytical functions and modulo, 3. reaggregate by these groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
WITH numbered_table AS (
  SELECT x, rowNumberInAllBlocks() as row_num, intDiv(row_num, 5) AS "section"
  FROM 
    (SELECT arrayJoin(splitByString(' ', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit')) AS x)
)

SELECT arrayStringConcat(groupArray(x), ' ')
FROM numbered_table
GROUP BY section
ORDER BY section
```

First, I split the input text into an array of individual words using `splitByString()`. Then, I used `arrayJoin()` to turn this array into a column, and then assigned a row number to each element.

Then, I assigned a section number to each word which indicates which 5-word grouping the row belongs to.

Finally, I grouped on the section number and used `arrayStringConcat()` and `groupArray()` to group into wordings of 5. Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for the answer! 
I nderstand that it is not possible a query  using more than one initial text value. But, would it be possible if the result, instead of transposing it into rows, were in an array that contains subarrays of five words?

Comment: Thanks greatuniter!! I ran yout query and works fine, I had an error in the sql!

Answer (score 1):

Clickhouse apparently offers the [substringIndex()](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-functions#substringindexs-delim-count) function.

You can use it get the first five words of your text like this, by specifying a space as its delimiter.

```
SELECT substringIndex(texts.text, ' ', 5)
```

You can get words 6-10 like this, taking the first ten words, and then taking the last five of those.

```
SELECT substringIndex(substringIndex(texts.text, ' ', 10), ' ', -5)
```

And so it goes. Words 11-15:

```
SELECT substringIndex(substringIndex(texts.text, ' ', 15), ' ', -5)
```

Comment: But I don't know length of text... this doesn't work using other texts examples :),